# OnActivityResult is not called on one Android device, but is on another

Tags: android, android-intent

I have four devices, on one, a Samsung Galaxy 6, I recently noticed that when I attempt to end and send back data from a crop activity the `onActivityResult` is never called. Instead, it oddly skips the class the `onActivityResult` is supposed to be on and goes back to the previous activity there.  No crashes occur, no nulls that are passed into this code

```
Bundle extras = new Bundle();
extras.putParcelable(RETURN_DATA_AS_BITMAP, croppedImage);

extras.putIntArray(RETURN_CROP_INFO, cropInfo);
setResult(RESULT_OK,(new Intent()).setAction(ACTION_INLINE_DATA).putExtras(extras));

finish();
```

Just the `onActivityResult` is never called.

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == Constants.INSTANCE.PICK_FROM_FILE ) {
                if (data != null) {
                    try {
```

Anyone have an idea what this might be? The Samsung and the other phone are both running lollipop.

This is the activation of the custom cropper.  The custom cropper code is fairly large though so I am not sure if posting here would make much sense.

```
private void performCrop(Uri picUri)
{
    // create explicit intent
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, CropImage.class);

    String filePath = picUri.toString();
    intent.putExtra(CropImage.IMAGE_PATH, filePath);
    intent.putExtra(CropImage.SCALE, true);
    intent.putExtra(CropImage.ASPECT_X, 3);
    intent.putExtra(CropImage.ASPECT_Y, 4);
    intent.putExtra("return-data", true);
    intent.putExtra(CropImage.SCALE_UP_IF_NEEDED,true);

    // start activity CropImage with certain request code and listen
    // for result
    startActivityForResult(intent, picCrop);
}
```

Comment: Sounds like a bizarre error! Good luck :-)

Comment: By never called, you mean you never hit a breakpoint set on the first line of onActivityResult?

Comment: Yes, I suppose that's what I mean't no breakpoints hit on the first line of onActivityResult.

Comment: Can you show the code that you use to start the crop activity?

Comment: Sure.  The crop activity I do use though is a Custom Cropper.  Its just the end results of all my attempts look fine.

Comment: This only happens on the Galaxy 6?

Comment: Yup, works on a nexus tablet 10, galaxy 4, and nexus 5. Just the galaxy 6 does this.

Comment: Get another SS Galaxy 6 and test if this issue happens or not :-)

Comment: I happened to my side too, the onActivityResult does not get called on Samsung Galaxy S6 Edge+ which introduced an odd behavior to our business flow...dang it... :(

Answer (score 1):

Just happened to accidentally figure this problem out.  I have been getting myself riled up on this problem.

First I attempted to remove the `bundle`, and pass in the image as a `byte array` into the `intent`. It still did not work after doing this.

Then I noticed that if I removed the image from the `intent` the code managed to reach the `onActivityResult` on all phones.  So I did a workaround by instead of passing the image in the intent I saved it in another class that I accessed in the `onActivityResult`.

I believe that what I got from this is that the Galaxy 6 phone was the only phone which I possess that created a bitmap larger than can be passed through an intent, as a `byte[]` or otherwise.

Hope this helps someone later!